Can´t subtract object from object with "difference" boolean modifier
As the title says, I am not able to subtract one object from another
I want to build an inlet, so I have a structure which I would like to subtract from a box
But either the box will disappear or the difference does not contain enough material, so the box is left with thin walls
How could I do it in a correct way?


Do you have a file as reference to see the geometry in depth?

I think we'll need to see your Blend file before we can work out what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.
